# django cms - how to make placeholders inheritable from base.html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I made in my base.html (which will be inherited from all other templates) this:

```
<a href="/./">
   {% placeholder "Logo-Image" or %}
     There is no Logo image yet.
   {% endplaceholder %}
</a>
```

I was in Startpage and uploaded a Logo image, worked well. but once I navigated to another pages, the uploaded logo isnot there, instead i see: `There is no Logo image yet.`

How can I make this placeholder also inheritable?

I tried in another page this:

```
{% show_placeholder "Logo-Image" inherit %}
```

but not a single sign of success

Comment: They should be inheritable, or at least they have been in previous versions of Django-CMS. As long as you're not over-writing the block...

Comment: I've had issues with using spaces in the name of a placeholder. Usually I hyphenate them.

Comment: @Brandon i made one-word placeholder and also hyphenated them, but the same issue - other pages dont get the image inherited. :(

Comment: @Brandon dang it.. i always miss new release notes and sit hours on old feature .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Django CMS has since version 3.0 a new tag called:

- **[static_placeholder](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#static-placeholder)**

to make it work:

just do in your base.html

```
{% static_placeholder "logo" or %}
   There is no Logo image yet.
{% endstatic_placeholder %}``
```

and all other pages inherit this.